# Using 'connmanctl config' to set static IP without wired connection

Tags: connman

I am currently using 'connmanctl config' to set static and DHCP settings with a wired connection. I'm curious if anyone has been successful with applying settings with the wire unplugged?

I would typically use 'connmanctl services' for a list of services then perform a string.match(blah, "ethernet_%w+_cable") to use that wired service name. I have been able to find and apply that service name with the ethernet cable unplugged BUT now when using 'connmanctl config':

connmanctl config ethernet_f8dc7a04ea82_cable --ipv4 manual 192.168.91.108 255.255.255.0 192.168.91.1 --nameservers 8.8.8.8

I get this error:

Error ethernet_f8dc7a04ea82_cable: Method "SetProperty" with signature "sv" on interface "net.connman.Service" doesn't exist

As you can see I have the service applied to the command and this is the same service name as when the cable is plugged in. This feature would be nice for equipment that needs to be pre-programmed before reaching the customer. I have also researched this error but can't find it being an issue with others the same as it is with my situation. Have also read many blogs, articles, etc...on trying to achieve this with nothing that jumps out at me.

...Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to perform this action via back-end with the code that I am using to configure. Just an example...settings are applied to /var/lib/connman/ethernet_?????*cable/settings. I created the adapter name with the MAC address because it does not exist until the network is detected, created the directory /ethernet*?????_cable then created an empty settings file on the fly. When programming and saving the settings via the equipment I am using I just insert the settings manually. When a network cable is plugged in and detected the settings you have applied work wonderfully.